# Snapshot isolation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

Hi can you please tell be for what kind of problem snapshot isolation may help me?

Like if I set this for a DB than what are the advantages and disadvantages?

```
    ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON

ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
```

Comment: Did you bother trying to read the documentation that EXPLAINS this?

Comment: There are pages and pages of [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb(v=vs.110).aspx) and you expect someone to magically intuit what your requirements are and manage to summarize it all into an answer?

Comment: So you both don't know when to enable this ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION and READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT? Good. Apart from pages of documentations can anyone please answer this in few lines, when you usually enables these two and what are the disadvantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must use 
SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON.

The reason for this is that we need to ensure that the report stored procs do not fail when inserts are going on in the staging tables, which could very likely happen if the report executes while the ETL service is executing a file load. By using snapshot isolation, we can ensure that the report works with a copy of the data prior to the insert transaction start and therefore will not be affected by the insert transaction.

**Note that we will be using snapshot isolation and not the read committed snapshot isolation.**

Here's a decent article that explains the snapshot isolation levels:

http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/